# after successful google authentication, app crashes while using real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my app, after a successful login with Google, it crashes when you get an instance of a firebase realtime database.

In my code, the Google sign works fine 
after that and there are parameters to get user info 
and a button on which I have set an `onClickListener` to upload user data in a realtime database.

`onCreate` *method I have*

```
 company_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip_company_name);
 mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 val_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_validate);
```

*this is* `onClick` *code for* `val_btn`

```
String comp_name = mCompanyName.getText().toString().trim();

        HashMap<String, String> datamap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        datamap.put("Company Name", comp_name);

        mdatabase.push().setValue(datamap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "updated  :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error  :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

if this code is used without google auth it works but it doesn't work with google auth. I have set up firebase rules correctly I assure that is not an issue.

the error is

> E/RunLoop: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener;

and

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mm.firebaselogin2-0Br4q5KgPHRacm8MT23I1w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mm.firebaselogin2-0Br4q5KgPHRacm8MT23I1w==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]

Comment: Please post stacktrace so we can understand the problem

Comment: Please post your firebase implmentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please upgrade your firebase database version to 17 or latest 19.2.0:

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade your `Firebase` dependencies to the latest version